# Multiple expressions in the command-line utility `rename`

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, rename

I am learning how to use the command-line Unix utility `rename` (see, for example, https://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/).

The manual for `rename` says that you can combine multiple renaming rules (notice, it is a synopsys of the usage where I remove other arguments for clarity):

```
rename [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr [ files ]
```

I try to do this on the following ariticial example.
I have a directory with files:

```
$ ls
01.php  02.php  03.php
```

I apply two transformations using one `rename` invokation:

```
rename -n -v -e "s/\.php$/\.htm/" "y/a-z/A-Z/" *
```

The expected behavior is that I will have:

```
$ ls
01.HTM  02.HTM  03.HTM
```

However, the output of `rename` is

```
rename(01.php, 01.htm)
rename(02.php, 02.htm)
rename(03.php, 03.htm)
```

that is, the second transformation (lowercase to uppercase characters) is not applied.

How to combine multiple expressions together?

Comment: What _should_ work is to put `-e` before each substitution, ie `rename -n -v -e "s/\.php$/\.htm/" -e "y/a-z/A-Z/" *`, but this gives an error. The documentation (`man rename`) is confusing, implying that you need `-E` to use the semicolon separator, but Toto's answer works, as do `rename -n -v -E "s/\.php$/\.htm/" -E "y/a-z/A-Z/" *` and `rename -n -v -e "s/\.php$/\.htm/;" -e "y/a-z/A-Z/" *`, as well as the quirky `rename -n -v -e "s/\.php$/\.htm/" -e ";" -e "y/a-z/A-Z/" *`. I have concluded that `-E` adds an implied semicolon between expressions, whereas `-e` requires explicit semicolons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine multiple expressions, separate expressions with a semicolon (instruction separator in Perl):

```
rename -n -v -e "s/\.php$/\.htm/; y/a-z/A-Z/" *
```

#### Additional variants based on the comments by @AFH

Another way (no need to use `-e`, just combine all expressions with `;`):

```
rename -n -v "s/\.php$/\.htm/; y/a-z/A-Z/" *
```

Yet another way (prepend each expression with `-e`; notice `;` in the end of the first expression):

```
rename -n -v -e "s/\.php$/\.htm/;" -e "y/a-z/A-Z/" *
```

Yet one more way (prepend each expression with `-E`, which adds `;` implicitly):

```
rename -n -v -E "s/\.php$/\.htm/" -E "y/a-z/A-Z/" *
```

Comment: I've extended your answer based on the comment by @AFH and accepted it. Thanks!